# Webflux Webclient - Error when sending HTTP2 requests as client to a HTTP2 enabled server

Tags: java, spring-webflux, http2

Small question regarding an issue while sending HTTP2 request to a server that is HTTP2 enabled please

**Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f**

The setup:
On server side, a Spring Webflux application 2.4.2, where http2 with mTLS is enabled. The java version is 11. The netty version is 4.

```
server.http2.enabled=true
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=server
server.ssl.key-password=x
server.ssl.key-store-password=x
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=x
server.ssl.trust-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store=truststore.p12
```

I know it is HTTP2 successfully enabled, because when I curl it, I see on the curl response.

```
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 4294967295)!
< HTTP/2 200
```

And in server side log, I do see `Feb/2021:+0000] "GET /route HTTP/2.0" 200 288448 24 ms`

Now, **the issue**:

A client using Webflux Webclient, initialized as such:

```
WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().protocol(HttpProtocol.H2).wiretap(true).secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getSslContext())))).build();
```

Note the .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2)

When using this Webclient to send the exact same request to this http2 enabled server, I see this exception:
First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: **485454502f;**

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f; nested exception is io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
```

After research online, 485454502f stands for HTTP/, but my server is HTTP2 enabled!

It is not a gRPC server, just HTTP2 enabled.

Hence, I do not understand why am I facing this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please post your java version, spring framework version, and reactor netty version

Comment: of course, updated

Comment: netty version can't be 4, current version of netty is 1.0.3 https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/releases also i want the client versions

Comment: Understood. I am using Spring Boot Webflux, so Netty is "managed" on my behalf

Comment: I can see in my bom

<dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${netty.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

    <netty.version>4.1.58.Final</netty.version>

Comment: I am running the entire dependency tree, you are correct, seeing

Comment: \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.3:compile

Comment: A bit of a hard time finding the netty client version. But since it is springboot, maybe it is the newest version, since they package it

Comment: Dont write in the comments, update your question. Also, what are the client versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Team:

Reactor Netty provides two types of SslContext configuration:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/tcp/SslProvider.SslContextSpec.html

You can provide either SslContext or SslContextBuilder.

Solution:

Either extend SslContext with a configuration that supports HTTP/2
Or provide SslContextBuild and Reactor Netty will be able to apply some default HTTP/2 configuration

I tried, both worked (thanks to Spring team)